# The "componentType" configuration parameter is required for the "search-engine-optimization" component

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php, seo, amasty

After upgrading amasty SEO toolkit from 1.17 to 1.18 i get this error when I try to access to the product edition from the administration page.

If a add an attribute to the group seo toolit optimisation in the attribute set I can access to the product but I'm not supposed to.

Thanks for help

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The "componentType" configuration parameter is required for the "search-engine-optimization" component.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set is_visible to true for amtoolkit_canonical and amtoolkit_robots attribute in catalog_eav_attribute table.